# Create a tag to distinguish between "MonetDB Assembly Language" and "Micro-Assembly Language"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation, tag-creation-request

Today I was browsing  the [mal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mal) tag (which refers to [MonetDB Assembly Language](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/MonetDB/MALreference)) and noticed that it’s been mistakenly used to tag questions regarding [Micro-Assembly Language](http://www.ontko.com/mic1/mal.html). I’m wondering if it would be appropriate to create a new tag to distinguish the two and avoid confusion even though the questions tagged [mal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mal) are not many. Maybe it would be more sensible to just edit the questions where the [mal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mal) tag is wrongly used.

Comment: The TLA strikes again! Better to have FLMA instead. Have you tried just being explicit and not using acronyms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were only 9 questions and the ambiguity was obvious so I just went ahead and did it.

All of the Micro-Assembly Language questions were already tagged with [mic-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mic-1) and the two seem intrinsically related. For these questions, I just removed the [mal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mal) tag. ([micro-assembly-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/micro-assembly-language) is also now a synonym of [mic-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mic-1).)

I retagged the MonetDB questions with [monetdb-assembly-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monetdb-assembly-language).